# TikZ - is it possible to apply a transformation to an image?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to apply a TikZ transformation to an existing image (complex) to obtain a predetermines distortion effects of a a lens, like these two?

[image]

Comment: This looks like a [nonlinear transformation](https://tikz.dev/base-transformations#sec-108.4) which is available but needs to be implented at the lower PGF level. But first, you need some mathematical way to describe that transformation.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel The impleentation of a transformation will have to be qualitatively because it depends on the lens one is talking about. The one you used below looks pretty good!

Answer (score 6):

I've tried to understand some of the formulas I found online.

1. Divide *x* and *y* value of coordinate by some value.
2. Calculate the distance to that point.
3. Calculate 1 + factor * distance for both the *x* and the *y* value.

I didn't get any interesting results by using an image (`\includegraphics`) or just plain text in `\pgftext` or a node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations}
\pgfset{
  barrel x factor/.initial=.3,
  barrel y factor/.initial=.3,
  barrel factor/.style={
    /pgf/barrel x factor/.evaluated={#1},
    /pgf/barrel y factor/.evaluated={#1}},
  barrel  width/.initial  =5cm,
  barrel height/.initial  =5cm,
  barrel size/.style={
    /pgf/barrel width/.evaluated={#1},
    /pgf/barrel height/.evaluated={#1}}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pgfbarreldistortion{%
  % xa, ya = original point
  \pgf@xa=\pgf@x
  \pgf@ya=\pgf@y
  % divide lengths by something (make it smaller)
  \pgfmathdivide@{\pgf@xa}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/barrel width}}%
  \let\barrel@x\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathdivide@{\pgf@ya}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/barrel height}}%
  \let\barrel@y\pgfmathresult
  %
  % calculate some radius
  \pgfmathveclen@{\barrel@x}{\barrel@y}%
  \let\barrel@radius\pgfmathresult
  %
  % 1 + factor * radius (but quicker)
  \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/barrel x factor}}{\barrel@radius}%
  \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{1}%
  \pgf@x=\pgfmathresult\pgf@xa
  \pgfmathmultiply@{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/barrel y factor}}{\barrel@radius}%
  \pgfmathadd@{\pgfmathresult}{1}%
  \pgf@y=\pgfmathresult\pgf@ya
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  barrel/.code=\pgftransformnonlinear{\pgfbarreldistortion},
}
\begin{document}
\tikz{
  \draw [help lines]    (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
  \draw [barrel, thick] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
}
\tikz[barrel factor=-.1]{
  \draw [help lines]    (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
  \draw [barrel, thick] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very impressive!